# Concatenating a string in a forEach loop js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, concatenation

I’m trying some tester code
I turn a string into UpperCase
Then split it to make it into an array and then loop through it using ES6 forEach loop
However when I try to concatenate ‘hello’ to the subject of the loop
It returns undefined

```
const string = 'abcd'
console.log(string.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(element => element += 'hello'))
```

And when I add join(‘’) to it it returns this

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating string.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(element => element +=('hello')).join')
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything accept its `undefined` default value. Please read some documentation ... [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#return_value), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#return_value)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `map` function to make any changes to array elements

```js
const string = 'abcd';

console.log(
  string
    .toUpperCase()
    .split('')
    .map(char =>
      char += ' hello'
    ).join(', ')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` is the proper way to do it, but if you need to use `forEach`, use it like that:

```js
const string = 'abcd'
var newstr = '';
string.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(element => newstr += element + 'hello');
console.log(newstr);
```